Extra items while segmenting characters in license plate
I'm working on a license plate detection project which is mostly for educational purposes.
I have gone through some process to locate the license plate and applied perspective transform upon the points of the plate rectangle.
Current issue: I can't seem to find a proper way to segment characters.
I have tried morphological operations but it sometimes ends up with some extra contours that I can't distinguish them from actual characters.
Usually there is a segment on the left of the plate or the lines on the right both of which I have marked on the image below:

Code:
mask = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
    ex_plate, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 17, 5
)

mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((3, 3)))

marker = cv2.erode(mask, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4, 20)))

obr = open_by_reconstruction(marker, mask)

obr = clear_border(obr)

obr = cv2.morphologyEx(obr, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, np.ones((3, 3)))

obr = hole_filler(obr)

These plates are labeled with correct plate number and I wanted to segment the characters so that I can train a model to identify them.
And this will be the pipeline for each image before reaching the model.

In place of adaptive thresholding, try thresholding on black using cv2.inRange().

Sorry, threshold on whatever color is the text color (black or white) using cv2.inRange().

@fmw42 Thank you that seems good. one problem tho. I don't have much experience with color processing and in my examples some images are more or less black than others how can I find a proper threshold here? or how can I somehow normalize the colors so that all 'blacks' are set to a specific value?

cv2.inRange() uses a range of values to allow some variation. Adjust your range to allow for your variation.  Perhaps  cv2.equalizeHist() might help. I have not tried that.

[mre] required, specifically source images. we can't do much without the source data. you showed an illustration. that's fine for discussion but we also need source data.
